# mysqld crashing almost every hour - mysqld invoked oom-killer

Tags: mysql, centos7, oom, oom-killer

I am running wordpress on a centOS digital ocean droplet

my mysql keeps crashing almost every hour -- with an out of memory error

manually restarting mysqld brings it back up via sudo service mysqld restart

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

here are my configurations and logs around the time of the crash:

**/etc/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]

max_connections         = 50
wait_timeout            = 3600
interactive_timeout     = 3600
open_files_limit        = 2048
table_open_cache        = 1024
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
max_heap_table_size     = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 256M
key_buffer_size         = 128M
join_buffer_size        = 2M
sort_buffer_size        = 2M
read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 256K
```

**/var/log/messages:**

```
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? virtballoon_oom_notify+0x25/0x70 [virtio_balloon]
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_kill_process.cold.29+0xb/0x10
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
/var/log/messages:Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 11402 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

**journalctl**

```
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: mysqld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 11418 Comm: mysqld Kdump: loaded Not tainted 4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.x86_64 #1
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Hardware name: DigitalOcean Droplet, BIOS 20171212 12/12/2017
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Call Trace:
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: dump_stack+0x5c/0x80
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: dump_header+0x6e/0x27a
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? virtballoon_oom_notify+0x25/0x70 [virtio_balloon]
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_kill_process.cold.29+0xb/0x10
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: out_of_memory+0x1ba/0x490
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xc0f/0xce0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x245/0x280
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: filemap_fault+0x3d8/0x860
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? hrtimer_try_to_cancel+0x25/0x100
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? pmd_devmap_trans_unstable+0x2a/0x40
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? alloc_set_pte+0x38a/0x480
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? _cond_resched+0x15/0x30
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __xfs_filemap_fault+0x6d/0x200 [xfs]
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __do_fault+0x20/0x80
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: do_fault+0x18d/0x3e0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? futex_wake+0x90/0x170
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __handle_mm_fault+0x539/0x6b0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: handle_mm_fault+0xda/0x200
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: __do_page_fault+0x22b/0x4e0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: do_page_fault+0x32/0x110
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: ? async_page_fault+0x8/0x30
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: async_page_fault+0x1e/0x30
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: RIP: 0033:0x55c787761910
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Code: Bad RIP value.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fc6eb4f7c10 EFLAGS: 00010202
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: 0000000000000000
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: RDX: 00007fc70037dd58 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 00007fc70037dd58
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: RBP: 00007fc6eb4f7d20 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000000000000f41e
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: R10: 00007fc6eb4f7960 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 0000000000000000
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: R13: 00007fc7004365f8 R14: 000055c78919a5f0 R15: 000000000000001e
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Mem-Info:
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: active_anon:398471 inactive_anon:13614 isolated_anon:0#012 active_file:127 inactive_file:3062 isolated_file:0#012 unevictable:0 di
rty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0#012 slab_reclaimable:6282 slab_unreclaimable:16715#012 mapped:25089 shmem:47803 pagetables:8459 bounce:0#012 free:13017 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 active_anon:1593884kB inactive_anon:54456kB active_file:508kB inactive_file:12248kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isol
ated(file):0kB mapped:100356kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB shmem:191212kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 724992kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB all_unreclaimable? no
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 DMA free:7424kB min:392kB low:488kB high:584kB active_anon:7720kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:96kB unev
ictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:16kB pagetables:76kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 1759 1759 1759 1759
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 DMA32 free:44644kB min:44660kB low:55824kB high:66988kB active_anon:1586164kB inactive_anon:54456kB active_file:508kB inact
ive_file:12152kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:2080740kB managed:1857680kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:3264kB pagetables:33760kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 DMA: 12*4kB (U) 14*8kB (UME) 14*16kB (UME) 42*32kB (UME) 19*64kB (UME) 9*128kB (UME) 5*256kB (M) 4*512kB (UME) 0*1024kB 0*2
048kB 0*4096kB = 7424kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 DMA32: 1126*4kB (UME) 986*8kB (UME) 547*16kB (UME) 215*32kB (UME) 78*64kB (UME) 25*128kB (UME) 7*256kB (UME) 9*512kB (ME) 2
*1024kB (M) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 44664kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 50995 total pagecache pages
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 0 pages in swap cache
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Free swap  = 0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Total swap = 0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 524183 pages RAM
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 55786 pages reserved
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: 0 pages hwpoisoned
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss pgtables_bytes swapents oom_score_adj name
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [  581]     0   581    29841     4014   262144        0             0 systemd-journal
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [  671]    81   671    16453      665   163840        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [  678]   993   678    31878      133   147456        0             0 chronyd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [  763]     0   763    22005      777   212992        0             0 systemd-logind
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [  807]     0   807   149740      633   385024        0             0 NetworkManager
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 1030]     0  1030    35492      246   294912        0             0 login
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 1031]     0  1031    56358       30    73728        0             0 agetty
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19456]   989 19456   254011     1927   184320        0          -900 do-agent
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [16142]     0 16142   146563     1980   503808        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [16201]     0 16201    27984      822   237568        0             0 sendmail
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [16221]    51 16221    17601      395   159744        0             0 sendmail
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19175]   991 19175   175468    25412   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19176]   991 19176   175976    25799   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19183]   991 19183   175999    27675   729088        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19184]   991 19184   174437    25598   712704        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19185]   991 19185   174953    24836   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19186]   991 19186   174945    24946   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19187]   991 19187   175991    26901   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19193]   991 19193   173913    24350   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19195]   991 19195   174937    24418   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19196]   991 19196   175495    26576   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19197]   991 19197   173880    24662   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19207]   991 19207   174970    25162   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19208]   991 19208   175473    26660   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19209]   991 19209   174950    24137   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19210]   991 19210   174979    25985   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19211]   991 19211   174946    25183   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19227]   991 19227   175434    25320   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19228]   991 19228   173963    24288   712704        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19229]   991 19229   175480    26312   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19230]   991 19230   175980    27686   729088        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19231]   991 19231   173936    24946   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19242]   991 19242   175464    26445   729088        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [19243]   991 19243   175455    26387   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30717]   991 30717   174336    23067   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30737]   991 30737   174850    24520   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30738]   991 30738   174840    23350   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30739]   991 30739   174914    24975   716800        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30740]   991 30740   173324    22868   704512        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30741]   991 30741   175294    26677   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30743]   991 30743   173860    23508   704512        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30744]   991 30744   174879    26783   720896        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30745]   991 30745   173342    22907   700416        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30746]   991 30746   174349    24161   708608        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [30747]   991 30747   174877    25364   724992        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [10335]  1001 10335    23312      342   221184        0             0 systemd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [10350]  1001 10350    79149     1082   319488        0             0 (sd-pam)
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28009]  1001 28009    58294      203    90112        0             0 bash
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28037]     0 28037    88552      264   307200        0             0 sudo
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28041]     0 28041    58792      167    94208        0             0 bash
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28114]     0 28114    39869      321   331776        0             0 sshd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28117]  1001 28117    39869      328   319488        0             0 sshd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28118]  1001 28118    58261      162    86016        0             0 bash
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28205]     0 28205    88552      261   294912        0             0 sudo
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [28208]     0 28208    58825      209    94208        0             0 bash
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [29844]     0 29844    29705      649   221184        0             0 nginx
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [29845]   991 29845    38341     1801   282624        0             0 nginx
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [31882]     0 31882    61464      219   114688        0             0 crond
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 8147]     0  8147    77482     3076   331776        0             0 rsyslogd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 8156]     0  8156    77886      165   188416        0             0 gssproxy
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 8169]   987  8169    40058      205   217088        0             0 rngd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [ 8182]    32  8182    16780      180   172032        0             0 rpcbind
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12562]     0 12562    37436      240   155648        0         -1000 auditd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12564]     0 12564    12121       94   139264        0             0 sedispatch
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12588]   998 12588   406517     1271   327680        0             0 polkitd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12597]     0 12597   158765     3689   442368        0             0 tuned
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12636]     0 12636    24081      598   221184        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12797]     0 12797    23242      226   204800        0         -1000 sshd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [21239]     0 21239   105551      493   438272        0             0 sssd
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [21241]     0 21241   107218      664   446464        0             0 sssd_be
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [21242]     0 21242   107745      405   466944        0             0 sssd_nss
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [11402]    27 11402   381489   104936  1277952        0             0 mysqld
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [11496]   991 11496   172880    18671   671744        0             0 php-fpm
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: [12890]     0 12890   198407    18847   901120        0             0 dnf
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 11402 (mysqld) total-vm:1525956kB, anon-rss:419744kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos kernel: oom_reaper: reaped process 11402 (mysqld), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL 8.0 database server.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos systemd[1]: Starting MySQL 8.0 database server...
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos mysql-check-socket[12938]: Socket file /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock exists.
Sep 16 17:51:38 centos mysql-check-socket[12938]: No process is using /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which means it is a garbage, so it will be removed automatically
Sep 16 17:51:39 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Sep 16 17:51:39 centos systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 16 17:51:39 centos systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL 8.0 database server.
```

**free**

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1873588     1563424       69388      191208      240776       19560
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Comment: Post the output from [mysqltuner.pl](http://mysqltuner.pl).

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck What do cores, SSD and NVME have to do with memory management?

Comment: If you do not have any, your options are limited.

Comment: @,wilsonhauck True that your options are not as good without SSD, but we managed for well over 20 years before SSDs were a thing. CPU is not a big factor. RAM caching and application tuning are..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is 1 or both of 2 things. My bet is on the second.

It's possible your database is simply too big that you don't have adequate memory for it.

Much more plausible is that memory management is struggling. Linux is designed to work with swap, and you don't have any.  You should create a swap file (even if it's relatively small) and enable swap. **just having swap sends signals to Linux which are important for memory management and will likely solve your problem**

Swap can be either a partition (preferred) or a file (often easier and quite OK, but slightly less performant). You likely also want to set `vm.swappiness` to a low value (like 0 or 10). This sends the memory manager a signal to use swap as a last resort, so your system does not go unresponsive when swapping chunks of memory to disk.

Comment: Make your swap space 6GB to tolerate slow rather than dead.

Comment: @WisonHauck - How do you get to 6GB - I'd suggest 500 megs is more then adequate.  The problem is is there is NO swap.  You don't need a lot of swap for the OS to get its hints.  Also, with vm.swappiness it won't neccessarily have a significant slowdown.  The idea is not to swap, its to provide hints to the memory manager so OOMs don't happen.

Comment: Please review this URL for many observations.  https://itsfoss.com/swap-size/   My preference is - Make your swap space 6GB to tolerate slow rather than dead.

Comment: That link has values all over the place, none as high as 6 gigs. Its final conclusion is 1gig (based on table at the end, with no hibernate).  Its also overly simplistic as it ignores weighting of use of the RAM SSD vs caching influenced by swappiness. On HDD, 6 gigs of swap on a 2 gig ram system with VM.swappiness at 69% has taken down many a server as disk io blocks all access.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out sort_buffer_size and join_buffer_size. Changing those is almost always counterproductive.

How many temporary tables (implicit or explicit) do you ever have at any one time? If more than very few and they are big you will need to reduce the max_heap_table_size.

Answer (score 0):

Lower these to no more than 1% of RAM.

```
max_heap_table_size     = 256M
tmp_table_size          = 256M
```

This should probably be no more than 500M for a 2GB setup:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Turns out my php-fpm was misconfigured. I fixed it by adjusting child processes for PHP-FPM (Nginx)

[Here's a link to explain the fix](https://www.kinamo.be/en/support/faq/determining-the-correct-number-of-child-processes-for-php-fpm-on-nginx)

Comment: Congratulations and Thanks for the link to your explanation of the php-fpm configuration details.